# When IsEnabled changed RelayCommand CanExecute do not change IsEnabled anymore

Tags: mvvm-light

i have problem.
When i change button IsEnabled property (purpose of this is global read only mode), RelayCommand CanExecute do not change IsEnabled anymore, but CanExecute method is called!.
I see that command is still attached and called.
What i am missing?

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
using GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Command;
```

with:

```
using GalaSoft.MvvmLight.CommandWpf;
```